# Isomorphy between graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am asked to find a undirected graph that is Isomorphic to a directed graph. Does that even make sense?
[directed graph with 3 nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYFAG.png) 
My first thought was a cycle with 3 Vertices, but I don't feel this should be the solution since 2 Isomorphic graphs have the same amount of edges. But with undirected graph we also have the "advantage" that the edges can be read for ex {a,b}={b,a}. Thanks in Advance

Comment: A strict isomorphism does not make sense. However, the graph you have given is essentially a 3-cycle, if we are willing to weaken the notion of isomorphism by identifying 2-cycles with undirected edges.

Comment: Just take a single vertex. No edge, no problem. ;)